# Can image displayed by plt.imshow() be saved as a numpy array?

Tags: python, matplotlib, image-processing

This is a line from my code:

```
plt.imshow(Equalized, cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'), vmin = 0.55, vmax = 0.80)
```

Here, `Equalized` is a 2-D image. The image displayed by this is the following:

[image]

**fig(i)**

Now, I wish to save the exact output image (without axes, borders, etc.) -
[image]

**fig(ii)**

as a numpy array for further manipulations. How can I do that? If there is no way to do that, then in that case, kindly help me by telling me how can I replicate the effects of cmap, vmin, vmax inside *imshow()* to generate the exact replica of the output.

**Edit**: On incorporating the answer of Lucas M. Uriarte as given below, I am able to save it as a numpy array in a variable, but on displaying it I get the following image:

[image: fig(iii)]

This image is the same as the `Equalized` image in the beginning.
Can I get fig(ii) as a numpy array in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, it is possible if you store the output as variable.

```
output = plt.imshow(Equalized, cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'), vmin = 0.55, vmax = 0.80)
# output should be a matplotlib.image.AxesImage object
np_array = output.get_array()
```

**Edit for updated question**

After verifying what the color map and vmin vmax does to the data matrix of the figure. the following lines demonstrate that the matrix under the figure is not modified, but only the scale of the colormap is changed, between images.

```
fig1 = plt.imshow(Equalized, cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'), vmin = 0.55, vmax = 0.80)
fig2 = plt.imshow(Equalized)

(fig1.get_array()  == fig2.get_array() ).all()
>>> True
```

That is to say if you want to normalize you data you should do it
previously, vmin vmax do a linear normalization. you can do that on your data as follow

```py
normalized_matix = data_norm = (Equalized - vmin) / (vmax - vmin)
```

and you should always use the colormap in gray if you want it to be gray

Comment: Thanks for your input, I incorporated it. But it is not making any difference as such. Kindly look into the edit made in the question above.

Comment: @Key76 I need some time to make some test, I will answer ASAP

Comment: @Key76, just to inform that by default the figure will never be plotted in gray scale if you reuse plt.imshow() on the array since by default the colormap of the figure is viridis. I still need to check the vmin and vmax. but I also do not think these are affecting the array behind the image

Comment: @Key76 I have update the answer regarding your question

Comment: Yes, the default colourmap is 'viridis'. So somehow, I need to change the colourmap of the image to 'gray'. That I feel can be done using 

`cm = plt.get_cmap('gray')
gray = cm(Equalized)
plt.imshow(gray)`

This gives me the grayscale image and converts `Equalized` to a 3d matrix. Now, the only thing that is remaining is replicating the effect of vmin and vmax. With that, it would be done.

Comment: With regard to your updated answer... I will surely try it and get back. Thank you.